# How to add permission to save App Configuration and Store Listing on Google Workspace Marketplace SDK (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to give permission to a developer to edit the "App configuration" and "Store Listing" pages at the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK API on Google Cloud, with the current permissions the "save" button [is not enabled][1].

The only solution i found so far was to add the Editor role to his IAM user, i wish i was able to add the exact permissions to perform this action, but the appmetadata.records.create and appmetadata.records.update permissions GCP suggested do not exist and neither are listed anywhere.

Those are the current permissions they have:

Compute OS Login,
Google Workspace Add-ons Developer,
OAuth Config Editor,
Service Account User,
Viewer,

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am in the same boat.

Comment: same problem here cant find the appmetadata.records.create permission anywhere as an option to add to the user